# Excel drops all the data to one cell after saving to CSV

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that copies range `Range("A100:AC101")`. There are no merged cell or anything else. There is a value in each cell.

Can somebody tell me why after saving to CSV Excel drops all the data to two cells:

- A100:AC100 are in A1
- A101:AC101 are in B1

Data before code operation in Excel:

[image]

Data in saved CSV file:

[image]

I have tried to comment out:

```
ActiveSheet.SaveAs Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\" & "file1.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False

ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

and data seems to be copied correct - each value in own cell. Then after saving to CSV things start to go wrong...

Here is my code:

```
Sub ExportRangeToCsv()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Templates").Range("A100:AC101").Copy

Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'avoid from "save prompt window"

Workbooks.Add

ActiveSheet.Paste

ActiveSheet.SaveAs Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\" & "file1.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False

ActiveWorkbook.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'set to default

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the data being shown in one cell when you load the CSV file back in Excel? If you open the CSV file in a text editor, does the data look good?

Comment: If I open file in Notepad for example it drops "," after each cell that is not correct I guess. As you can see from screenshot it drops "," after each cell value also... 1,2,3,4,5,6. There are no "," in original Excel (screenshot #1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To properly import CSV data in Excel, use the "From Text" wizard under the "Data" tab. It will let you specify a delimiter ("," in your case).

Your data seems to be exporting to CSV properly, the added commas are there to separate the cells (hence the name Comma Separated Values).

[Importing *.csv formatted data into Excel](https://www.hesa.ac.uk/support/user-guides/import-csv)